# realloc failing on second call

Tags: c, realloc

I am trying to add a bunch of WCHARs to a buffer. This function is what adds it to my buffer..

```
DWORD add_to_buffer(BYTE *databuffer, WCHAR *path, WCHAR *value_name, DWORD type, BYTE *data, DWORD data_size, DWORD already_added) {
    DWORD path_size = wcslen(path) * 2;
    DWORD value_name_size = wcslen(value_name) * 2;

    WCHAR *type_name = reg_type_to_wchar(type);
    DWORD type_size = wcslen(type_name) * 2;


    DWORD total_length = already_added + path_size + value_name_size + type_size + data_size;

    *databuffer = realloc(databuffer, total_length);
    
    CopyMemory(databuffer, path, path_size);
    CopyMemory(databuffer + path_size, value_name, value_name_size);
    CopyMemory(databuffer + path_size + value_name_size, type_name, type_size);
    CopyMemory(databuffer + path_size + value_name_size + type_size, data, data_size);
        
    return total_length;
}
```

On the second call to the `add_to_buffer()` the realloc() fails. I am basically calling this function over and over, while adding information to it and making it bigger as needed. I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue as everything in VS looks correct when going into the function. databuffer is not getting freed anywhere outside of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up levels of pointer indirection. For example, in your line, `*databuffer = realloc(databuffer, total_length);` your are (on the left-hand side) dereferencing the `databuffer` variable but, inside the call, you are not.

If you want your function to *modify* the pointer (which it does), then you need to pass a pointer to that pointer, so that the modified value (new address) is available to the calling module. Like this:

```c
DWORD add_to_buffer(BYTE **databuffer, WCHAR *path, WCHAR *value_name, DWORD type, BYTE
 *data, DWORD data_size, DWORD already_added) { // Pass a "databuffer" as a DOUBLE pointer
    DWORD path_size = wcslen(path) * 2;
    DWORD value_name_size = wcslen(value_name) * 2;

    WCHAR *type_name = reg_type_to_wchar(type);
    DWORD type_size = wcslen(type_name) * 2;

    DWORD total_length = already_added + path_size + value_name_size + type_size + data_size;

    // It is also bad practice to overwrite the argument in "realloc" calls; save to a
    // temp, so that you can check for failure ...
    BYTE *temp = realloc(*databuffer, total_length); // Not the "*" before databuffer!
    if (temp == NULL) { // Allocation failure ...
        // Here, place code to handle/signal the error
        // But note that we STILL HAVE THE ORIGINAL POINTER!
        return 0; // and return a value that indicates failure
    }
    *databuffer = temp; // Succeeded: we can now safely reassign the passed pointer.
    
    // We now need to also dereference the double pointer in the following calls ...
    CopyMemory(*databuffer, path, path_size);
    CopyMemory(*databuffer + path_size, value_name, value_name_size);
    CopyMemory(*databuffer + path_size + value_name_size, type_name, type_size);
    CopyMemory(*databuffer + path_size + value_name_size + type_size, data, data_size);
        
    return total_length;
}
```

Comment: Of course, you will also need to make the appropriate modification to any calls of your function (typically, adding the `&` operator before the first argument in those).

Comment: And don't guess the size of WCHAR being 2, , use `sizeof(WCHAR)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
*databuffer = realloc(databuffer, total_length);
```

Here you assign value returned by realloc to first byte of databuffer. You shouldn't dereference databuffer.

Comment: But then the calling module will **never** know what the new value of the reallocated pointer is. Needs a double pointer argument.

Comment: Good point, I concentrated on what's wrong with the code, not on how to fix it properly

Answer (score 1):

**realloc return value:**
"This function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, or NULL if the request fails."
On the 2nd call, there should be no more available space to realloc... i think the easiest way is to change it as:
`*databuffer = realloc(databuffer, total_length);`
`if(databuffer == NULL) {`
   `*databuffer = malloc(total_length);`
`}`